# Does anyone know a good practice to use when developing for the system.directory services class?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, active-directory, adsi, directoryservices

I'm trying to create a data access later using `System.DirectoryServices`. I'd like to use the MVC 2 framework and have all my views be mostly strongly-typed. Does anyone know any good way to this?

For example I started creating a Group Entity:

```
public class Group
{
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

And an abstract interface:

```
public interface IGroupRepository
{
    List<Group> Groups { get; }
}
```

I am confused about developing the GroupRepository using the system.directory services. Connecting to a SQL database is easy there are examples everywhere but I have no been able to find any using the System.directory sevices in conjunction with a class using MVC. Has anyone tried to do something like this? Any great would be

Comment: Incidentally, with regards to your repository, LINQ (or at least lambdas) are your friend. instead of exposing a list, expose a `Function Get(ByVal Query As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of T, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of T)` (Excuse the VB) You can then call `Repository.Get(Function(x) x.Name = "GroupName")`

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 3.5 (and if you use MVC 2, chances are good you are), you should check out the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace which brings you lots of strong .NET classes and types for many of the directory objects you're dealing with on a regular basis - no need to re-invent the wheel (yet again!).

Check out this great article in MSDN magazine on how to use this S.DS.AM namespace:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

**Update:** for reasons I don't totally understand, the simple approach of using a `UserPrincipal` as a model for a ASP.NET MVC view doesn't work - it seems as if ASP.NET MVC cannot "find" any properties on that object.

So the approach would have to be to do something like this:

- grab your `UserPrincipal` (or `DirectoryEntry`) from Active Directory
- define a separate `ViewModel` - this is just a class that holds properties, like first name, last name and so forth
- you can either fill that ViewModel class yourself, or you can grab some help like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to make mapping from `UserPrincipal` (`DirectoryEntry`) to your ViewModel easier
- then display (or edit) your ViewModel class in a standard ASP.NET MVC view
- handle any possible updates by transferring any changes back from the ViewModel to the "proper" object and persisting that object

It's a bit more involved than I'd like it to be - but I quite honestly don't see how else you can do this otherwise.

Comment: The AccountManagement namespace looks really nice. I guess I am confused about integrating that with the MVC framework. What would my model looks like for example with a user and how would the model get populated with data using this namespace? If anyone can provide a short but helpful example that would be great. I'm having trouble getting started here.

Comment: For example, let's say you want to update a user. You have a View that displays a textbox for firstname and one for lastname. Using mvc, how would something like this get updated with the Accountmanagement framework ?

Comment: @marc_s see my previous comment

Comment: @Jim: I tried something today, but I was stumped by the fact that it seems ASP.NET MVC cannot generate a decent view for a `UserPrincipal` - for whatever reason that escapes me... I'll have to work on that sample a bit more - I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @marc_s I've been thinking, if you can provide an example using the system.directoryservices namespace that would suffice as well. Any ideas? anyone?

Comment: @Jim: updated my answer - if you want the VS2010 project I've used (C#), send me an e-mail (my address is in my profile) and I'll be glad to send that over to you - it's too much to just post here...